# Remover elementos de uma Lista Pararela Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basicamente eu quero remover os elementos de uma lista segundaria com base no resultado de uma outra lista. Tenho duas listas:

`lista_8 = ['', '', 'Preco', '', 'Preco', '', '', 'Preco']`

```
lista_n = ['positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo']
```

**Segue a lógica:**

Quando o elemento da `lista_8` for vazio, o elemento da `lista_n` também fica vazio, caso contrário mantém o resultado (positivo ou negativo).

**Meu código está assim:**

```
for w in lista_8:
    if lista_8[w] == 0:
        lista_n[w+1] = 0
```

`print lista(n)`

**Segue erro que acontece:**

if lista_8[w] == 0:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: O `w` representa cada elemento de `lista_8`, não é o índice. Você vai precisar usar o `enumerate` para conseguir manipular o índice. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

Comment: Você está tentando percorrer a `lista_8` com o `for`, quando você tenta verificar se `lista_8` na posição `w`, ocorre o erro pois ele espera um numero inteiro da posição na lista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando o [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) é possível numerar uma lista facilitando trabalhar com a mesma.

```
lista_8 = ['', '', 'Preco', '', 'Preco', '', '', 'Preco']
lista_n = ['positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo']

for w, value in enumerate(lista_8, 0):
    #if lista_8[w] == '': funciona desta maneira também
    if value == '':
        lista_n[w] = ''

print("lista_8\n")
print(lista_8)
print("\nlista_n\n")
print(lista_n)
```

Execução do código: https://onlinegdb.com/B1rJCwwnX

Comment: dentro do `for` você já tem a variavel `value` que contém `lista_8[w]` - pode usar a msma no `if`: `if value == '':`

Comment: @jsbueno sim verdade, não atentei a esse detalhe. Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O Python possui, no pacote `itertools`, a função [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), que **remove** de um objeto iterável os valores conforme o valor de outro iterável.

```
def compress(data, selectors):
    # compress('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1]) --> 'A' 'C' 'E' 'F'
    return (d for d, s in zip(data, selectors) if s)
```

Isto é, para:

```
A = ['', '', 'Preco', '', 'Preco', '', '', 'Preco']
B = ['positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'negativo', 'positivo', 'positivo', 'negativo']
```

Ao fazer `compress(B, A)` o resultado seria `['negativo', 'negativo', 'negativo']`, mas não é exatamente isso que queremos. Podemos, então adaptar essa função criando uma `compress_with_replacement` que, ao invés de remover o elemento, substitui por um valor definido:

```
def compress_with_replacement(data, selectors, replace=''):
    # compress_with_replacement('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1], '') --> 'A' '' 'C' '' 'E' 'F'
    return (d if s else replace for d, s in zip(data, selectors))
```

Assim, o retorno de `compress_with_replacement(B, A)` será:

```
['', '', 'negativo', '', 'negativo', '', '', 'negativo']
```

**Obs.:** O retorno é, na verdade, um gerador. O resultado acima foi obtido convertendo o gerador para uma lista.

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo pelo [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) e assim também, segue abaixo:

```
i_temp = -1
for w in lista_8:
    i_temp = i_temp + 1
    if len(w) == 0:
        lista_n[i_temp] = 0
print(lista_8)
print(lista_n)
```